# Qt C++ Clickable file path link

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

to preface, I know literally nothing about Qt.

I'm wondering if it's possible to make text in a GUI that will open a file path when clicked.

The text should be coloured blue like a hyperlink, and the file should be highlighted in its folder in file explorer the way "Open file location" does in Windows.

Comment: There are two things: 1) The style of text in a label or button can be changed. Thus, you can show it like a link (blue color, underlined). 2) You are responsible yourself to provide a specific action for the click. I'm not aware that there is a portable option to open the file explorer in OS / desktop you're application is running in. I'm afraid you have to use platform specific code for the platforms you intend to support. In general, to start another process from your appl. `QProcess` can be used. To communicate to an already running... It depends.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like I can use QProcess in windows to do this, unsure about Mac and the many Linuxes https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/851523/How-Can-I-Open-A-Folder-And-Have-File-Selected-In#answer1

Comment: `QProcess` is available for all target platforms. The difference is what you start on these platforms. Concerning Linux, I'm even not sure if there is "The file explorer". This is subject of the desktop environment, isn't it? (I'm common with Linux and other *ix OSes in general but I don't use them in daily business...)

Comment: I'm thinking about the relationship between Nautilus and Ubuntu, couldn't that be considered the file explorer? For headless setups I have no idea, I'm probably on interested in supporting Windows and Mac

Comment: In this case, I would consider two things: 1) There might be a environment variable which can be evaluated for this purpose (but I don't know how it could be named). 2) Make it a configurable option of your program. - You even could consider to combine both options so that the 2nd can be used if the 1st failed.

Comment: Just set html content on `QLabel` and you done.

Comment: Please tell me how to use html to trigger a qt process?

Comment: To open files in the file browser, I suggest you look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#details

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. The Qt class QLabel is a good starting point. You'll probably want to look at [this function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#linkActivated) for manipulating the display characteristics (such as turning blue into purple).